# How to generate thumbnails from AVMutableVideoComposition

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `AVMutableVideoComposition` which is comprised of some image layers composed over the avasset and I want to be able to generate a thumbnail for it. How can I do this? Usually I can generate thumbnails using `AVAssetImageGenerator`, but I can't find a way to do it for an `AVMutableVideoComposition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer myself. You have to create an `AVComposition` from your `AVMutableVideoComposition` and then generate the thumbnails for that using `AVAssetImageGenerator`.

Comment: can you give an example code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass AVMutableVideoComposition into AVAssetImageGenerator. For example:

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()

generateThumbails(asset: composition, composition: videoComposition)

func generateThumbails(asset: AVAsset, composition: AVVideoComposition) {
  let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
  generator.videoComposition = composition
  let times: [NSValue] = []
  generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: times) { _, image, _, result, error in
    //...
  }
}
```